# How to be sure data is on disk after fwrite?

Tags: c++, file, synchronization, fwrite

I have a program, where one thread writes to file, and other reads (with synchronization). But the written and read values aren't equal from some time. Actually reader reads the right number of elements, but values are differ. Can this be the problem of not pushing data to disk? Although I call fflush after writing, but how can I make sure it's written, so I can reject this version.
Os - windows.

```
FixedSizeQueue::FixedSizeQueue(const std::string& filename, size_t size)
    : size_(size)
    , head_(0)
    , tail_(0)
{
    fopen_s(&file_, filename.c_str(), "w+");
    InitializeCriticalSection(&critical_section_);
}

void
FixedSizeQueue::push_values(int* values, size_t count)
{
    Logger::report("Called push_values");
    EnterCriticalSection(&critical_section_);
    size_t free_items = (tail_ > head_) ? size_ - tail_ + head_ : size_ - head_ + tail_;
    if (count > free_items)
    {
        Logger::report("Buffer is full, can't push new values.");
        exit(1);
    }

    size_t till_end = (tail_ >= head_) ? size_ - tail_ : head_ - tail_;

    if (count < till_end)
    {
        fseek(file_, tail_ * sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
        int g = fwrite(values, sizeof(int), count, file_);
        assert(g == count);

        tail_ += count;
    }
    else
    {
        fseek(file_, tail_ * sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
        int h = fwrite(values, sizeof(int), till_end, file_);
        assert(h == till_end);
        fseek(file_, tail_ * sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
        h = fwrite(values + count, sizeof(int), count - till_end, file_);
        assert(h == count - till_end);

        tail_ = count - till_end;
    }
    fflush(file_);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&critical_section_);
}

size_t
FixedSizeQueue::get_values(int* values)
{
    Logger::report("Called get_values");
    EnterCriticalSection(&critical_section_);
    const size_t item_count = (tail_ >= head_) ? tail_ - head_ : size_ - head_ + tail_;
    if (tail_ > head_)
    {
        fseek(file_, head_ * sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
        fread(values, sizeof(int), item_count, file_);
    }
    else
    {
        fseek(file_, (size_ - head_) * sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
        fread(values, sizeof(int), size_ - head_, file_);
        fseek(file_, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(values + size_ - head_, sizeof(int), tail_, file_);
    }

    head_ = tail_ = 0;

    LeaveCriticalSection(&critical_section_);

    return item_count;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Operating system? Is reading and writing on the same file handle? Fopen mode(s)?

Comment: Windows. Yes, it's the same function called in two threads, so with the same file handle.

Comment: `Yes, it's the same function called in two threads, so with the same file handle.` That makes no sense. I mean, if you use the same `FILE*` variable in both threads. And what are you passing to fopen?

Comment: I used fopen_s with w+, since visual gave a warning.

Comment: Two threads do other staff, and some time just call that functions. I wasn't trying to make parallel read and write.

Comment: Don't use files as IPC mechanisms and certainly not as inter-thread communcation mechanisms. There are plenty of better solutions.

Comment: I wouldn't if I would decide the way to do this :) This is just what I have to do.

Comment: Well, it should work that way (even without fflush). Something is wrong with your code, possibly the synchronization. You should show the relevant code parts. Maybe you can construct a small sample program which is only about file reading/writing, with the irrelevant stuff cut out.

Comment: Well, I can post only that writing and reading functions.

Comment: By logs I can see that synchronization works. When I debug they are called in exact way, push_values writes correctly, but after that when get_values calls, the read data aren't the same, although the size is the same.

Comment: The C++ language has no guarantees of when data will be transferred to a file using `fprintf` or `fwrite`.  This functions are allowed to buffer the data.  The `fflush` function will tell the platform to write the buffers to the file.  However, the OS can delay writing to the file or the harddrive could also delay writing to the file.  In order to determine when the data content is written to the file may require special platform API.

Comment: Thank you, Would it work if I close and open file again?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews How is OS level and below relevant if the same file handle is used? The OS surely will give some written data for a read as it should be, even if it is not on the disk.

Comment: @Curiosity To rule out any program-level buffering not aware of thread stuff, and several other possible problems, it might be a good idea to make another thread in charge of the file (alone), and the other threads telling this thread what to do with it (again synchronized, of course)

Comment: @deviantfan: file handles have nothing to do with data being written to a disk drive (except they identify a file).  I'm talking about when does the OS decide to write the data to the file.  If using a hard drive, the hard drive could cache the data and write the data at a later time.  The Windows API has a function where you can give more attributes for writing data that are not available in the `fwrite` function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ...but I'm not talking about when it is written to disk, but why it should be the reason for not reading what was written. If I read something not yet on disk, I'll get the current content from (OS...) cache. [And I'm well aware of the buckload of CreateFIle options]

Comment: When you call read function, it goes to OS, if written data is still in OS, it's returned. I think the same is also for hard drives, if it buffers also, it'll return from buffer, not from disk.

Comment: @Curiosity Exactly. When reading, every something with buffer between you and hard disk will give you data either from buffer or disk, depending on what's newer. The only possible buffer problem is one within your programs file functions (fread...), because they may not know threads very well. That's why I suggested a separate thread above.

Comment: What the... This is why I prefer linux to windows. Under linux there is no binary and text files. Windows handles them specially. When file is opened in text mode, fseek just doesn't work. Call doesn't complain, it even returns 0 which means everything is OK, but it can do anything (and often does what you want) . The conclusion is, don't program under windows, especially if you are linux programmer, or you can read all documentation of functions you use, because there is no logic in windows functions. Stupid OS.

Comment: @Curiosity fseek does work, but in "text mode", every \n in the data is given as \r\n (ie. two byte) to the program (and when writing it out again, every \r\n is converted back to \n). ... So, the problem is solved?

Comment: Yes, I opened it in binary format. Yes you are right, When I was debugging memory, I saw something like this:  08 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 0a 00 00 0b 00 00 00 ...   0b 00 00 00  was written above last byte of 0a 00 00 00, probably that's because I was writing numbers starting from 0, and reach to enter's ascii code, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This archived KB article helped us with this: https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/066/Q66052/

When we initially opened our file using fopen_s, we included the "c" mode option as the LAST OPTION:

```
fopen_s( path, "wc") // w - write mode, c - allow immediate commit to disk
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=vs-2019

Then, since it's Windows, when you want to force a flush to disk, call

```
_flushall()
```

We made this call before calling

```
fclose()
```

We experienced the exact issue you described and this approach fixed it.

From that above KB article:

*"Microsoft C/C++ version 7.0 introduces the "c" mode option for the fopen()
function. When an application opens a file and specifies the "c" mode, the
run-time library writes the contents of the file buffer to disk when the
application calls the fflush() or _flushall() function. "*